# Include functions in class from another file in python

Tags: python, django

I'm writing a SOAP web service for Django which will have a lot of functions.
To keep it clean, I would like to split it in several files.

How do I "include" my functions code into my class (like in PHP).

For example:

```
class SOAPService(ServiceBase):
  #first file
  from myfunctions1 import *
  #second file
  from myfunctionsA import *
```

Should behave like:

```
class SOAPService(ServiceBase):
  #first file
  def myfunction1(ctx):
    return

  def myfunction2(ctx, arg1):
    return

  #second file
  def myfunctionA(ctx):
    return

  def myfunctionB(ctx, arg1):
    return

   ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Python lets you inherit from multiple classes, so go ahead an put your methods into a separate base class and inherit from it, too.

Also, python lets you pull in from other files with the import statement.

Comment: Please see my comment on Andrew's answer about mixing classes.

Answer (score 0):

Although there are several ways to do this, the first one I would recommend is to create *mixin* classes from both files.

So in your main module

```
import myfunctions1
import myfunctionsA
class SOAPService(ServiceBase,myfunctions1.mixin,myfunctionsA.mixin):
    pass
```

and in your included modules myfunctions1, myfunctionA etc.

```
class mixin:
    def myfunction1(self):
        return
    def myfunction2(self, arg1):
        return
```

Comment: The problem is, according to this comment, that I'm not supposed to mix ServiceBase with other classes http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24268065/restrict-spyne-soap-service-with-oauth2-provider#comment37556928_24268065

Comment: In this case I think it is ok. I didn't see anything in ServiceBase that would cause this mixin style to break.